# JSON.parse(obj) not working correctly; it's throwing err. online parser shows correctly

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, ecmascript-6

[image]

I'm trying to build a chatApp for portfolio based on few technologies like flask and on front-end side vanilla to better understand the spin. Straight into the point. I need to render for new users an events based on sockets(...).

I do send from back-end flask list of object to the jinja2 than grab it in JS file and try to Parse it to JSON file to be able to have better manipulation of this, but all time. I'm getting string and parse method throw different error. I did try much different REGEX to replace single quotes for double and tilde on different combination but still stuck on my stack thinking. Below I put images about problem.

[image: Without '' everything fine correctly...]

```
// Make sure that i parsed an string not object...
let json = JSON.stringify(loggedUsers.textContent.trim());
console.log(json);
//json = jsonCorecter(json);

json = json.replace(/"/g, "`");
json = json.replace(/'/g, '"');
json = json.replace(/`/g, "'");
console.log(json);
console.log(typeof(json));
json = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json);
console.log(typeof(json));
```

Comment: *" I do send from back-end flask list of object to the jinja2"* Seems like this part is not generating valid JSON. Make sure that it does. Trying to "fix" the quotation marks via string replacement is destined to break sooner or later. What's the actual return value of `loggedUsers.textContent.trim()` ?

Comment: There you have a link to photo: https://ibb.co/1TRKgt5 that console.log(are)
loggedUsers.textContent.trim() === "[{'username': 'Sunni', 'sessionID': '68f62b9665014d16ae6e7e816b98791f', 'randomID': '771287'}, {'username': 'Sunni', 'sessionID': '68f62b9665014d16ae6e7e816b98791f', 'randomID': '771287'}, {'username': 'Sunni', 'sessionID': '68f62b9665014d16ae6e7e816b98791f', 'randomID': '771287'}, {'username': 'Sunni', 'sessionID': '68f62b9665014d16ae6e7e816b98791f', 'randomID': '771287'}(...)...'}]" without trim i've got extra whitespaces... and this is a string OFC

Comment: @Sunni Please don't post links to photos, post the data. And Felix is right, you should fix your backend if it doesn't produce valid JSON.

Comment: @Bergi Alright! Still newbie user of that site. Will notice that for the future! Understand that but it is not commercial app and i'm learning so... I do prefer take my DATA as a string trim()'ed it of whitespaces, change some regular expression to achive validate STRING for JSON.parse() method it should also work this way right?

Comment: @Sunni No, there's too many edge case where it won't work. Fixing the server side that generates the JSON will be much easier.

Comment: Can someone explain this please... https://ibb.co/KjgPLmd how is it possible? to same string can have diffrent result of same method?

Answer (score 0):

Alraight! i do figured out... I get a string and used stringify() method on it to be 100% sure about that this is a string. I didn't read details how this function work but it might pack our string for extra quotes and than our string passed as argument into function aren't comply with requirements...